# Laravel iterate complex object

Tags: laravel, object, foreach, view, loops

I'm having some trouble to iterate over the object (below) as it has the main **User** data and then the **profile**, **jobs** and **photos** arrays.

I'm getting the errors `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Thanks in advance for any help here as I seem to got into a mental loop and cannot find what I'm doing wrong.

In the Controller iI call the DB:

```
$team = \App\User::where('users.state', 1)->with('profile','jobs','photos')->get();
$team->jsonSerialize();
```

What I've done to loop in the view for the variable that carries the object  that gives me an error

```
            <li>
                <a href="/{!! str_slug(trans('menus.lawyers'), '-') !!}/{!! str_slug(trans('global.words.partners')) !!}" title="{!! trans('global.words.partners') !!}">{!! trans('global.words.partners') !!}</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    @foreach($team as $member)
                        @foreach($member->jobs as $jobs)
                            // just display if partner | socio
                            @if ($jobs->slug== 'socio' || $jobs->slug == 'partner')
                                @foreach($member->profile as $profile)
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/{!! str_slug(trans('global.words.lawyer_male'), '-') !!}/{!! $member->profile->full_name_slug !!}" title="{!! $member->profile->full_name !!}"><img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('/images/staff/thumbs/'.$member->photos[3]->filename) }}" alt="{!! $member->profile->full_name !!}"> {!! $member->profile->full_name !!}
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </li>
```

The object (reduced version):

`0 => array:15 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "guid" => "0b6e0ad2-7daa-4c2b-907a-d095ab577851"
    "name" => "John Doe"
    "slug" => "john-doe"
    "email" => "mp@testingsite.com"
    "state" => 1
    "ordering" => 0
    "created_by" => 1
    "updated_by" => null
    "deleted_by" => null
    "created_at" => "2018-02-12 19:59:47"
    "updated_at" => "2018-02-12 19:59:52"
    "profile" => array:23 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "user_id" => 2
      "full_name" => "John Doe McNamara"
      "full_name_slug" => "john-doe-mcnamara"
      "short_name" => "John Doe"
      "short_name_slug" => "john-doe-mcnamara"
      "gender" => "male"
      "birth_date" => "1973-05-05"
      "work_start" => "2000-01-01"
      "work_end" => null
      "biography" => "John Doe started the firm in 1900."
      "experience" => "A couple of years"
      "education" => """
        UCLA;\n
        Berkley
        """
      "affiliations" => ""
      "notes" => ""
      "hits" => 3
      "state" => 1
      "ordering" => 0
      "created_by" => 1
      "updated_by" => null
      "deleted_by" => null
      "created_at" => "2018-02-12 20:07:00"
      "updated_at" => "2018-02-24 12:32:52"
    ]
    "jobs" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:15 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "guid" => "45f91a68-d219-42b1-8980-8cb77d6688b4"
        "type" => "Lawyer"
        "slug" => "lawyer"
        "department" => "Law"
        "notes" => null
        "language" => "en"
        "state" => 1
        "ordering" => 4
        "created_by" => 1
        "updated_by" => null
        "deleted_by" => null
        "created_at" => "2018-02-11 01:43:04"
        "updated_at" => null
        "pivot" => array:2 [▼
          "user_id" => 2
          "job_id" => 1
        ]
      ]
      1 => array:15 [▼
        "id" => 11
        "guid" => "fcf9f310-eeb1-4ff4-b133-6c80d6bf3b7f"
        "type" => "Partner"
        "slug" => "partner"
        "department" => "Law"
        "notes" => null
        "language" => "en"
        "state" => 1
        "ordering" => 1
        "created_by" => 1
        "updated_by" => null
        "deleted_by" => null
        "created_at" => "2018-02-11 01:49:38"
        "updated_at" => null
        "pivot" => array:2 [▼
          "user_id" => 2
          "job_id" => 11
        ]
      ]
    ]
    "photos" => array:4 [▼
      0 => array:14 [▼
        "id" => 5
        "guid" => null
        "user_id" => 2
        "type" => "profile"
        "directory" => "staff"
        "subdirectory" => "profile"
        "filename" => "john-doe@1-100.jpg"
        "state" => 1
        "ordering" => 0
        "created_by" => 1
        "updated_by" => null
        "deleted_by" => null
        "created_at" => "2018-02-12 20:03:31"
        "updated_at" => null
      ]
      1 => array:14 [▼
        "id" => 6
        "guid" => null
        "user_id" => 2
        "type" => "bgs"
        "directory" => "staff"
        "subdirectory" => "bgs"
        "filename" => "john-doe@1-100.jpg"
        "state" => 1
        "ordering" => 0
        "created_by" => 1
        "updated_by" => null
        "deleted_by" => null
        "created_at" => "2018-02-12 20:03:49"
        "updated_at" => null
      ]
      2 => array:14 [▶]
      3 => array:14 [▶]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:15 [▶]
  2 => array:15 [▶]
  3 => array:15 [▶]
  4 => array:15 [▶]
  5 => array:15 [▶]
  6 => array:15 [▶]
  7 => array:15 [▶]
  8 => array:15 [▶]
  9 => array:15 [▶]
  10 => array:15 [▶]
  11 => array:15 [▶]
  12 => array:15 [▶]
  13 => array:15 [▶]
]`

Comment: I'm not sure why that happens. Try locating which `foreach` in particular causes that error. But is there any particular reason you're calling `$team->jsonSerialize();`. I don't think it's doing anything.

Comment: I've tried to not call any method and get the object, tried the `->toArray()` and now the `->jsonSerialize();` to figure out if this could be one of the reasons.

Comment: Don't call any of these. The query will return Laravel `collection`, which is basically objectively better than an array. And JSON doesn't make sense since you're using it with PHP. Also, I'm pretty sure it's literally not doing anything since you'd need to explicitly override the `$users` object. Either way, try locating which `foreach` is causing you the error. You probably have the cached view in the error message. You can navigate to it in most modern text editors using `Ctrl + P` and writing in the first few characters.

Comment: Looks line the error is coming on the `@foreach($member->profile as $profile)` loop

Comment: To get it to work, I just found that I don't need the `@foreach($member->profile as $profile)` loop. Then what I have to call is, for instance, `{!! $member->profile['full_name'] !!}` and this way it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error you used `JsonSerializeed`

Here is the code the that you can use

```
$team = \App\User::where('users.state', 1)->with('profile','jobs','photos')->get();
```

and in your view iterate over it as you already doing

```
 <li>
                <a href="/{!! str_slug(trans('menus.lawyers'), '-') !!}/{!! str_slug(trans('global.words.partners')) !!}" title="{!! trans('global.words.partners') !!}">{!! trans('global.words.partners') !!}</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    @foreach($team as $member)
                        @foreach($member->jobs as $jobs)
                            // just display if partner | socio
                            @if ($jobs->slug== 'socio' || $jobs->slug == 'partner')
                                @foreach($member->profiles as $profile)
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/{!! str_slug(trans('global.words.lawyer_male'), '-') !!}/{!! $member->profile->full_name_slug !!}" title="{!! $member->profile->full_name !!}"><img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('/images/staff/thumbs/'.$member->photos[3]->filename) }}" alt="{!! $member->profile->full_name !!}"> {!! $member->profile->full_name !!}
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: While I agree that could cause a problem if he's using it without explicitly overriding the `$users` variable it doesn't do anything. Also if he does, the first `foreach` should work and `$member->jobs` should throw a different error (calling a method on a non-object).

Comment: Laravel levaral, used the code you suggested but still getting the error.

Comment: Seems like where I'm getting the error now is at the `@foreach($member->profile as $profile)`

Comment: @McRui yess you are right  @foreach($member->profile as $profile) is generating an error